# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, select2

estoy haciendo la edición de un producto y este tiene la posibilidad de ponerle variaciones de producto y necesito cargar en un select multiple, las marcadas y las que no están marcadas.

Por un lado recupero de mi tabla Variations todas las variaciones generadas de este producto:

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | variant  | valor     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 1          | color    | negro     |
| 3  | 1          | color    | rojo      |
| 4  | 1          | color    | blanco    |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+

$variations =  Variation::select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(valor) AS valor'), 'variant')
                            ->where('product_id', $producto->id)
                            ->groupBy('variant')
                            ->get();
```

Entonces imprimo en mi vista lo siguiente:

```
@foreach ($variations as $varia)
  <div class="form-group select-container-{{$varia->variant}}" style="position:relative;">
      <div class="deplegables" style="text-transform: capitalize; ">{{$varia->variant}}</div>
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo variaciones" name="{{$varia->variant}}[]" multiple="multiple" id="{{$varia->variant}}">
           <option value="" selected>{{$varia->valor}}</option>
         </select>
         <a class="removeclass posiPapelera"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Esto funciona bien me saca tantos selects como variants haya, aunque el `concat` me lo separa por `,` y me lo pone todo en una selección, es algo que no se como solucionar que si viene: "opcion1,opcion2" me imprima en el select= opcion1 opcion2.

Bien pero ahora el problema es que hasta ahora saco los que tengo seleccionados/creados. Pero la variante color por ejemplo tiene más colores que los seleccionados.

Esto lo tengo construido así:

Tabla Atributos:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | slug  |     
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | Color  | color |
| 3  | Talla  | talla |    
+----+--------+-------+
```

Tabla Terminos:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id | atributo_id | termino  | slug      |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 2           | color    | negro     |
| 3  | 2           | color    | rojo      |
| 4  | 2           | color    | blanco    |   
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

Entonces yo lo que quiero sacar, es que si traigo impreso un select multiple de colores, me saque los valores que tengo de la tabla `Variations` y luego con un `join` traer el resto de colores disponibles por ejemplo.

Estoy intentando así pero sin éxito.

En el controlador bajo la consulta `$variations` hago esto:

```
foreach($variations as $item){
   $todasOpciones = DB::table('atributos')
     ->where('slug', $item->variant)
     ->join('terminos', 'atributos.id', '=', 'terminos.atributo_id')
     ->select('terminos.*', 'atributos.id')
     ->whereNotIn('terminos.slug', $item->valor)->where('estado', 1)->get();
}
```

Hago un foreach para poder acceder al arreglo, como podeis ver primero cojo la tabla atributos y la comparo con `->where('slug', $item->valor)` así selecciono el atributo que necesito, luego hago un join para sacar términos que tiene ese atributo y por último le digo que no seleccione los que ya están.

Espero haberme explicado bien y me podais ayudar, me devuelve este error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/highas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 870
```

**Edición**
El problema de que me vienen concatenados y me lo pone junto en el select ya lo he solucionado pasando el string a un array.

```
$array=explode(',',$varia->valor); 

@foreach ($array as $item)
    <option value="" selected>{{str_replace("-"," ",$item)}}</option>
@endforeach
```

---

**Tras las repuestas de los compañeros:**

En el controlador:

```
$variations =  Variation::select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(valor) AS valor'), 'variant')
   ->where('product_id', $producto->id)
   ->groupBy('variant')
   ->get();
foreach($variations as $item){
   $todasOpciones = DB::table('atributos')
      ->where('atributos.slug', $item->variant)
      ->join('terminos', 'atributos.id', '=', 'terminos.atributo_id')
      ->select('terminos.*', 'atributos.id')
      ->whereNotIn('terminos.slug', explode(',', $item->valor))->get();
}
```

En la vista:

```
@foreach ($variations as $varia)
   @php $array=explode(',',$varia->valor); @endphp
   <div class="form-group select-container-{{$varia->variant}}" style="position:relative;">
     <div class="deplegables" style="text-transform: capitalize; ">{{$varia->variant}}</div>
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo variaciones" name="{{$varia->variant}}[]" multiple="multiple" id="{{$varia->variant}}">
        @foreach ($array as $item)
          <option value="{{ $item }}" selected>{{str_replace("-"," ",$item)}}</option>
        @endforeach
        @foreach ($todasOpciones as $item)
           <option value="{{ $item->slug }}">{{ $item->termino }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
        <a class="removeclass posiPapelera"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

Añado dos imagenes para hacerme entender mejor:

Si solo hay un select impreso:
Sale perfecto, tengo seleccionada dos tallas, pero puede elegir entre las restantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si por lo contrario por ejemplo es un producto, con dos tipos de variaciones, me salen las restantes del segundo select en el primero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver me mezcla los atributos de papel con los de talla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que el atributo valor es un `string` y debería ser un array.

```
->whereNotIn('terminos.slug', explode(',', $item->valor))
->where('estado', 1)
->get();
```

Si sólamente haces `[$item->valor]`, obtendrás sólo un array con un elemento que será la cadena concatenada.

---

Lo que tienes que hacer es agregar una nueva propiedad a tu array de objetos llamado `$variations`. Para cada select tenga su propio "todasOpciones".

```
$variations = $variations->each(function($item, $key){
      $item->todasOpciones = DB::table('terminos')
          ->select('termino', 'slug')
          ->where('termino', $item->variant)
          ->whereNotIn('slug', explode(',', $item->valor))
          ->get();
});
```

Dado que `$variations` es una instancia de Collections después de usar `get()`, entonces puedes usar each().

Posteriormente, en tu vista haces lo siguiente:

```
@foreach ($varia->todasOpciones as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->slug }}">{{ $item->termino }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Perdona, me sigue devolviendo el mismo error!

Comment: En la vista... En la vista sigo teniendo que tener el otro foreach que tenia no?? `@foreach ($array as $item)`

Comment: Ohhh!!! ahora si!! que bien muchisimas gracias @L.Flor que de gran ayuda me has sido!!!

Answer (score 1):

El error esta a nivel de tu query derivado de la siguiente línea:

```
->whereNotIn('terminos.slug', $item->valor)->where('estado', 1)->get();
```

Debido a que como notas en [la propia doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) el método **`wherNotIn`** espera como primer argumento el nombre de la columna sobre la cual evaluará y el segundo es un array de valores.

Quedando así:

```
->whereNotIn('terminos.slug', [$item->valor])->where('estado', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Hola @BetaM gracias por tu respuesta, ahora no devuelve error, pero no excluye los que ya están en el select multiple

Comment: @Miguel a falta de mas tiempo esperemos que alguien mas participe en la pregunta

Comment: Gracias, sigo investigando...